# Sony xperia 4.1.2 is not firing the onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt() method?

Tags: android, webview

I am having a problem to fire onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt() method when my apps needs location permission. It is working almost all devices but not working only Sony xperia 4.1.2. So what can I do now? Any suggestion please? And see the location setting screen of my device.
[image]

Comment: did you get it working? I'm having the same problem with an xperia 4.1.1 and some other phones

Comment: Ya. I solved the problem. The problem is not in xperia device. Actually this 4.1.1 version can't fire the required method. So I simply check the version and manually fire it. Thanks.

Comment: but how do you do it? if it's supposed to be called from javascript, I'm not sure how to handle this